# State containing 2D arrays is being mutated

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-hooks, state

I'm making a GO game in React.js and I want have the board jump to previous board states stored in history. I am storing the board states within a 2D array. Updating the board to the most recent state is no problem. My issue is that all past board states stored in history are being mutated to the latest board state.

[Demo image of GO game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd4lK.png)

Heres the codeSandBox link to the whole code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-rain-e9qh74?file=/App.js

This is the code to set my history state, you can see here I'm creating a nested array filled with the string 'E'.

```
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([createBoardState(size)]);

  function createBoardState(size) {
    let array = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
      array[x] = [];
      for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        array[x][y] = "E";
      }
    }
    return array;
  }
```

This is my state update function, I spread the history array (which contains my board state) then added another array called nextSquares which is the current board state.

```
  function handlePlay(nextSquares) {
    const nextHistory = [...history.slice(), nextSquares];
    setHistory(nextHistory);
    setCurrentMove(nextHistory.length - 1);
  }

  function jumpTo(nextMove) {
    setCurrentMove(nextMove);
  }
```

When I try to update the board state to a previous state stored in history nothing changes because all past board states are updated to the most recent state. I know its updating all the arrays because I'm logging the history and seeing that every previous array gets updated as I make new moves.

Comment: `[...history, nextSquares.map(r => [...r])]`

Comment: `Array.slice` creates a shallow (contrasted with a deep) copy, so you are retaining references to the original game state.

So, whichever code is altering the "latest" game state in fact changes all of the history, as they are currently the same object reference.

I would recommend either a full on deep copy of your game state to avoid this duplicated reference, or  altering history to be a condensed snapshot (e.g. a string representation of the board) that you can then reverse when rewinding/replaying time.

Comment: Did the above comments answer your question?